# Batch String Comparison with Symbols

Tags: batch-file, string-comparison

How do I do a string comparison with a string containing symbols?
In my particular case, I am trying to compare a string to "%1" (including quotations).

ex:

```
if "%var%" neq '"%1"' ( echo %var% )
```

I have tried various forms, my latest looks like:

```
if "%var%" neq """%%1"""
```

Comment: You're trying to see if the variable `%var%` contains the literal string `"%1"`?

Comment: Why does %var% already have quotes in the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the quotes in the variable with something else while comparing. And in case `var` already has that symbol in those places do the comparison with two different characters to make this trick universal:

```
if "%var:"=*%%var:"=#%" neq "*%%1*#%%1#" echo Yay!
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent batch from think you're talking about the `%1` script argument, you need to double up the percent signs. It also doesn't hurt to not use quotes around the two sides of the `==` operator, but you don't have to.

```
@echo off

cls
set /p var=

if [%var%]==["%%1"] echo yes
pause
```

If you want to use quotes, you can.

```
if "%var%"==""%%1"" echo yes
```

Comment: If `var` has an unknown value that may include spaces this method will fail due to a syntax error.

Comment: And the second code will display a syntax error in case `var` has quotes AND spaces inside it like `"a b c"`.